# Ideal Janrain integration with existing ASP.NET membership database

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, rpx

I've got Janrain working for SSO and no problems there. But once I get the user's identification and put it into the ASP.NET membership database, don't I also need to set a password? I guess I can put in a dummy password for each user, but that would leave everyone open to compromize if someone finds what this password is?

Answer (score 1):

make the dummy passwords random?

Comment: Yeah, you can make the dummy password random and HUGE....I think it accepts over 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can just generate a guid for the password and be done with it.